# React Navigation Navigating without the navigation prop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I'm trying to navigating without the navigation prop. Using React-navigation library for react-native. I have been following https://medium.com/@mattehr/react-navigation-easily-navigate-from-anywhere-in-your-app-7919bde4e42a and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

However when trying to use navigate I run into errors `TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` Even though I'm setting `setContainer`

`NavigationService.js`

```
    import { NavigationActions, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation'
    import type { NavigationParams, NavigationRoute } from 'react-navigation'

    let _container // eslint-disable-line

    function setContainer(container: Object) {
      _container = container
    }

    function reset(routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams) {
      _container.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
              routeName,
              params
            })
          ]
        })
      )
    }

    function navigate(routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams) {
      _container.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
          routeName,
          params
        })
      )
    }

    function toggleDrawer() {
      _container.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
    }

    function navigateDeep(actions: { routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams }[]) {
      _container.dispatch(
        actions.reduceRight(
          (prevAction, action): any =>
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
              routeName: action.routeName,
              params: action.params,
              action: prevAction
            }),
          undefined
        )
      )
    }

    function getCurrentRoute(): NavigationRoute | null {
      if (!_container || !_container.state.nav) {
        return null
      }

      return _container.state.nav.routes[_container.state.nav.index] || null
    }

    export default {
      setContainer,
      navigateDeep,
      navigate,
      toggleDrawer,
      reset,
      getCurrentRoute
    }
```

`index.js`

```
    render() {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true)
      return (
        <Provider store={this.store}>
          <App
            ref={container => {
              NavigationService.setContainer(container)
            }}
          />
        </Provider>
      )
    }
```

`action.js`

```
    import navigator from 'navigators/service'
    import { db, auth } from 'utils/firebase'

    import { ROUTE_HOME, ROUTE_LOGIN } from 'constants/routes'

    export const checkUser = () => dispatch => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          navigator.navigate(ROUTE_HOME)
        } else {
          navigator.navigate(ROUTE_LOGIN)
        }
      })
    }
```

Without pasting all my code into this thread. My app uses the switchNavigator which takes me to login screen or home screen depending on if I'm logged in. for example

```
    const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        AuthCheck: Authorize,
        Authorized: MainStack,
        Unauthorized: AuthStack
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthCheck'
      }
    )
```

Inside AuthCheck I have:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
    import { ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native'
    import styles from './styles'

    class Authorize extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        // check and fetch user
        const { checkUser } = this.props
        checkUser()
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    Authorize.propTypes = {
      checkUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    export default Authorize
```

When `checkUser()` is run in AuthCheck I get `TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` not sure how to fix this. It appears that _container is undefined even though before I have setup the navigators im calling:

```
    <App
      ref={container => {
        NavigationService.setContainer(container)
      }}
    />
```

Hope I explained this well enough any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever come right with this? I've been experiencing the same issue.

Comment: For this, I ended up getting it to work using the following documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html However I have now moved back to a redux implementation for my navigation using `react-navigation-redux-helpers` https://github.com/react-navigation/redux-helpers Supports V3 now